# You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysql-error-1064

G'Day

I have a php page that I want to edit an entry but for the life of me I can not figure out why it is coming up with this erro.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= po_postcode = '4060', email ='-', phone = '732997688', fax = '' WHERE id='1'' at line 1

HELP I am desperate and going insane. (Similar Code works on another page but not this one)....

Can someone PLEASE HELP.

{

```
<?php
/* 
 EDIT.PHP
 Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/

 // creates the edit record form
 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($id, $name, $po_street, $po_suburb, $po_state, $po_postcode, $email, $phone, $fax, $error)
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <table width="347" border="0" align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><p align="center"><img src="hartwell_banner.JPG" width="624" height="134" /></p>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td width="290" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="left"><h2 align="left"><p align="left"><a href="contact_insert.php">Enter a New Contact</a></p></h2></div></td>
     <td width="290" align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="left"><h2 align="center"><p align="center"><a href="index.php">Return to Index</a></p>
     </h2>
</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <table align="center">
 <tr valign="baseline">
      <td width="98" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="left">ID:</div></td>     
      <td width="329"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" size="40"  readonly = "readonly" /> * </td> 
    </tr>
     <tr valign="baseline">
      <td width="98" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="left">Name:</div></td>     
      <td width="329"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="40" /> * </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Postal Street </div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="po_street" value="<?php echo $po_street; ?>" size="40" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Postal Suburb</div></td>
       <td><Input type ="text" name="po_suburb" value="<?php echo $po_suburb; ?> " size="30" maxlength="50" >*</td>
       <tr valign="baseline">

    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">State</div></td>
      <td><Input type ="text" name="po_state" value="<?php echo $po_state; ?>" size="5" maxlength="3" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Postal Postcode</div></td>
      <td><Input type ="text" name="po_postcode" value="<?php echo $po_postcode; ?>" size="5" maxlength="4"/> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Email:</div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" size="40" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Phone:</div></td>
      <td><input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" size="12" maxlength="10" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right"><div align="left">Fax:</div></td>
      <td><input name="fax" type="text" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" size="12" maxlength="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> * Denotes Required Field<?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td colspan="2" align="right" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center"><img src="hartwell_costs.JPG" alt="" width="340" height="147" /></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form> 
  </body>
 </html> 
 <?php
 }



 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (isset($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid

 $id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $po_street = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['po_street']));
 $po_suburb = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['po_suburb']));
 $po_state = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['po_state']));
 $po_postcode = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['po_postcode']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
 $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));



 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($id == '' || $name == '' || $po_street == '' || $po_suburb == ''|| $po_state == '' || $po_postcode == ''|| $email == '' || $phone == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
  renderForm($id, $name, $po_street, $po_suburb, $po_state, $po_postcode, $email, $phone, $fax, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
  mysql_select_db($database_hartwell, $hartwell);
 mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET id= '$id', name='$name', po_street ='$po_street', po_suburb = '$po_suburb', po_state = '$po_state', = po_postcode = '$po_postcode', email ='$email', phone = '$phone', fax = '$fax' WHERE id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
}
else
{
 //if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
echo 'ID Not Valid!';
}
}
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
  mysql_select_db($database_hartwell, $hartwell);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$po_street = $row['po_street'];
$po_suburb = $row['po_suburb'];
$po_state = $row['po_state'];
$po_postcode = $row['po_postcode'];
$email = $row['email'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$fax = $row['fax'];


 // show form
 renderForm($id, $name, $po_street, $po_suburb, $po_state, $po_postcode, $email, $phone, $fax,'');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'No ID Value!';
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You have a stray equals sign: `= po_postcode =`. And `set id = '$id'` and `where id = '$id'` in one UPDATE is a bit strange. And if `id` is a number then don't quote its value, that's a bad habit that MySQL lets you get away with but all it does is make the server work harder.

Answer (score 4):

The error is right there in your query, just like the error message says:

```
, = po_postcode = '$po_postcode',
  ^
  |
  + this doesn't belong here
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the equal sign here:

```
'$po_state', = po_postcode

mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET id= '$id', name='$name', po_street ='$po_street', po_suburb = '$po_suburb', po_state = '$po_state', po_postcode = '$po_postcode', email ='$email', phone = '$phone', fax = '$fax' WHERE id='$id'")
```

Comment: Thanks. Could not see the skyscraper for the outhouses. Typo

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is here `= po_postcode = '$po_postcode',`